# Issue with my discord bot upon automatic startup on a raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, raspberry-pi4

Solution: Enable the delay for the reboot until wifi connection is established in the raspi-config settings.

When it automatically starts I get this

```
ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:default [Temporary failure in name resolution]
```

If I run the code manually it connects perfectly fine. Any idea what's causing this error?

Comment: Make sure you have network when the script is starting up. You did not post any details on how you start it but most starters have a dependency system making sure the network is up already.

Comment: I’m just using @reboot python3 (script directory)

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was fixed by inserting a sleep before the command (let the raspi boot completelly):

```
@reboot sleep 10 && python command
```